# Google Datastore Maximum length of a Custom Name Key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create an entity in datastore that has a key which is a composite key of other types that links to this entity. For an Example, let's say I have the following entities of the kinds

```
School { key:"abc-school-1" }
Student { key:"jon-doe"}
```

If I have a new kind "Report", I want the keys of it's entities to be the composition of School and Student.

`Report { key:"abc-school-1-jon-doe-year-1-report" }`

My question is, how long can this key get?

Will making the key long have significant performance impacts?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) you can find a list with all Datastore limitations. As it is not mentioned here about limitations on keys/properties, I think there is no one.

Take into consideration that there is a limitation for each entity size ( 1,048,572 bytes ).

Depending on how you manage your indexes the performance impact may be visible, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is NoSQL database, there is no limit on the key/property.
Also, if you are creating new composite index, there is no performance impact.
We recently created composite index on 10 Million records in less than 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment [datastore docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits) states that `maximum size for an entity key` is limited to 6KiB